# Wordpress - как &nbsp; заменить на пробелы в тексте записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

Скопирован был корявый текст и пробелы идут как `&nbsp;`, что ломает отображение сайта.

Вот код который я набросал:

```
//Little fix, &nbsp; to ' '
function replace_text($text) {
    if ($post->ID == 1546) {
        $text = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $text);
        return $text;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

Пробовал использовать preg_replace() - Отображается страница записи, но без текста вообще (только шапка, сайдбар и футер), хотя на другом сайте этот же код меняет номера телефонов в записях.

Wordpress - как   заменить на пробелы в тексте записи?

Comment: С помощью плагинов для поиска-замены в тексте. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: @SeVlad мне как раз интересно рабочую функцию написать и поделиться ей с сообществом, чтоб люди потом меньше времени тратили.

Comment: Люди, которые хотят тратить меньше времени и думают о безопасности - используют плагины из репо, а не чьи-то самопальные костыли. Но интерес написать самому - похвально. Но другое. :)

Comment: Last updated: 2 years ago о какой безопасности Вы говорите?

Comment: И что (в данном случае)? Плагин в репо? Значит уже без найденных уязвимостей.. Одноразовая операции по замене текста, после чего плагин удаляется - и кого ты испугался? :)  Но не нравится этот - есть масса других, актуальных. Но не таких удобных, как этот. Дело хозяйское. Я указал на правильный путь и  сказал "например", а не только этот.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте стандартную php `htmlspecialchars_decode` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Вот такой код тоже отображается страница записи, но без текста вообще (только шапка, сайдбар и футер)

`function replace_text($text) {
 if ($post->ID == 1546) {
  $text = htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
  return $text;
 }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');`

Comment: Или я что то не понимаю в вопросе или вы усложняете сделайте вывод htmlspecialchars_decode($text) без функций raplace

Comment: Semenov тот же самый результат, есть еще предположения, идеи?